# After inserting the character ñ in a table the character will be converted like Ã±

Tags: sql-server, mysql, oracle, java

when we are inserting the character ñ from application in a table the character will be converted like Ã±.

I have verified general log and binlog the charecter is showing correctly ñ but when reading from table the charecter looks like Ã±. But when we are doing insert directly on table by logging in to DB the charecter inserting properly and looks like perfectly. Table column is "id_name varchar(200) COLLATE latin1_bin DEFAULT NULL ".

How to insert charecter ñ on table properly from application.

Comment: Hi there, welcome to the site. I see you tagged your question with 3 database systems (sql-server, mysql and oracle). I suppose only mysql applies?

Comment: If you are using "normal" strings - why are you using a BINARY collation? I would be using something like UTF 8. Can you follow the instructions [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-collation/)? Looks like you need [UTF8 with a Spanish collation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)!

Comment: See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

Answer (score 1):

Before answering your question about how to get ñ (and any other latin character) properly inserted via the application, let's take a step back and review what has happened so far.

Id_name uses the Latin1_bin collation. When you login directly to the database and insert ñ, code point 241 from the Windows-1252 code page is  used. Try this test, insert one ñ and then run "Select length(id_name) from ;  You'll get the value 1 returned for the one character. Next, do the same thing using the application and then rerun the select. You'll get the value 2 returned.

In UTF8, the ñ character is the multi-byte code point U+00F1; it's also known by the combined code points 195 and 177. When you look up code points 195 and 177 in the Windows-1252 code page, which is the one used by Latin1_bin, you'll see the characters that occupy those code points are Ã and ± .

Let's tie it all together. Your app server is sending ñ to your database as the UTF8 value U+00F1 (also known as 195 177). Your id_name column is not UTF8 so the database then does what it has been programmed to do and inserts the two code points 195 and 177, which results in the characters Ã and ± being displayed when selected using the Latin1_bin collation.

Unfortunately, you might have data corruption in the columns now if any dml was done directly at the database level that involved Latin1_bin characters above code point 127. A quick check is to do something like "Select id_name Collate UTF8 from ". You'll hopefully be able to see any out-of-place characters resulting from having injected single-byte code points above 127 into a column the app has been feeding multi-byte code points in that range. You'll need to look hard at this and fix any issues you find.

If your data looks good, and if Latin1_bin is the collation you want to use for the column, you'll need to set the app's collation to something that's compatible with Latin1_bin, which means something that uses the Windows-1252 code page. Alternatively, you could change your database to match your app server's collation, though there might be data conversion work to do. Ultimately, you'll have to decide what characters your business needs to support and then conform your environment to match. These approaches will result in the ñ going in properly and displaying properly.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252
http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?utf8=dec

Answer (score -1):

If you use latin1 as your encoding, characters such as japanese words, hebrew, including your ñ character will be converted to [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake%20). You should change your encoding from latin1 to UTF-8.

Comment: ñ is **Latin** character, and not japanese, hebrew, etc. It's contained in 1252 code page reflected in all Latin collations, so it can be stored as ascii character using any Latin collation, and not as unicode